# Error installing gem failed to build gem native extensions -- cannot load such file -- mkmf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eventmachine, mkmf

RoR is nice, but sometimes makes me want to bang my head against the wall (and it's probably my fault anyway). I'm simply trying to install the `Thin` web-client gem, and when I run `sudo gem install thin`, I get the following error (it requires the installation of the eventmachine gem first):

```
    sudo gem install thin
    Fetching: eventmachine-1.0.1.gem (100%)
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing thin:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
            /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
            from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
            from extconf.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

I've searched for the "cannot load such file -- mkmf" error, but most issues seem to be surrounding the fact that it was available in 1.8-dev but not 1.8, but as I'm running 1.9.3 I figured I had mkmf - which I verified with `locate mkmf`:

```
    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb
```

The directory that mkmf is located in is obviously not under the /usr/lib/ruby/... directory - I'm not sure if this is my problem or not, but it maybe enough to jumpstart one of you experts out there as to what's going on and what the solution could be.

Also, I've used RVM to install ruby 1.9.3 rather than just a `gem install`...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you're using RVM, you shouldn't ever be using 'sudo'.  Using sudo calls libs and such out of the rvm path.  Try just a flat

```
gem install thin
```

and see if that helps.

~Kevin

Comment: That was it - thanks @devneck! Unfortunately, I think I've installed a few gems with the use of `sudo` so that may cause me some pain down the road, but I'll make sure to keep this in mind.

Comment: Also, there was an issue when I tried to start the thin web server, but it was fixed by simply adding `thin` to the Gemfile.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error to this outside of rvm, I found that i needed to install `ruby-devel`

Comment: That was it! Amazon Linux

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem in Ubuntu 12.04 . Solved by:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

Comment: I had actually tried these before trying to install thin, but I would still get the error mentioned above. The trick for me was to install the gem without prefacing the command with 'sudo', but I think the steps you've shown are still important in the process.

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04, I just had to do:
'sudo apt-get install build-essential' followed by 'sudo gem install thin'

Comment: For ubuntu 14.04 I did sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

Answer (score 2):

Try below command it will helps to resolve the problem

```
sudo gem install thin -- --with-cflags=\"-O2 -pipe -march=native -w\"
```

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Cheers

Comment: I had to do `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev build-essentials` on a new install of Ubuntu 16.04