# Ruby servers (thin, unicorn, puma, etc) can only be installed using `bundle install`

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I can install other native extensions fine with rbenv's `gem install`.  However, all servers (minus webrick) give me this problem:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error
>   installing thin:
>
> ```
>        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /custom_dir/.rbenv/versions/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> ```

The output of `gem_make.out` is the same as the previous line.  `bundle install` and `bundle install --deployment` work fine. The servers perform fine with `bundle exec`. However, I can't figure out why `gem install puma|thin|etc` fail.  It's not important, but I'm wondering what is happening in case it's a symptom of another issue.

Another symptom: If I install thin or unicorn, I get the same error based on their dependencies. In other words, it tells me to look at `kgio/gem_make.out` or `raindrops/gem_make.out`, etc. However, if I install their dependenccies separatly: kgio, raindrops, etc., they install fine (using `gem install kgio`).  But, when I try to install the final package, thin, unicorn, etc., it gives me the same error regarding `ruby extconf.rb` with no further details.

Another symptom: I can only compile Ruby 2.0 if I leave out rdoc/ri documentation. I get a `make: *** [rdoc] Error 137` if I compile Ruby with documentation. I believe this is related to why the server gems won't compile. I have managed to install `unicorn` manually w/o Rubygems,, using `Ruby 2.0`.

`Ruby 1.9.` compiles fine, along with rdoc/ri documentation. `puma` and others install fine, even with rdoc/ri doc generation. So it seems it is a problem with:

1. Ruby 2.0
2. rdoc/ri generation

*Update:* Installing `Ruby 2.0` with RVM (instead of rbenv) worked. Installing all other server gems works fine and the executables (eg `puma`) work fine. RVM seems to be doing something extra that rbenv/ruby-build is not.

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208525/error-installing-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extensions-cannot-load-such-f

Comment: run this: `where bundle` and see if this matches your Ruby 2.0 installation's bin path.

Comment: Do you mean `which bundle`?  `where` is not installed on the system.

Comment: @Keval: I'm not using `sudo` for any of these calls. Is that what you thought the problem was? Thanks anyway.

Comment: did you try out the last answer in that link involving apt-get install

Comment: Yes. The package is called `ruby-dev` in ubuntu, `ruby-devel` in other distros like Fedora.  I still get the same error: `.../bin/ruby extconf.rb`  It's not complaining about missing libs. Esp. since the gems install fine with `bundle install` so I have all the necessary  libs. I also checked the answer above it... `build-essential ... zlib1g...` Everything is up to date and installed.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood here, but have you tried to do `bundle update`? That will fix dependencies as well as installing the gems.

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood. I said, `bundle install` works fine. That also includes `bundle update`. It's when I install with `gem install [name]` that it fails. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In my instance, it turned out to be a lack of memory on the virtual machine I was compiling on. I only had 256MB provisioned. Once I bumped it up to at least 512MB RAM this issue went away.

I was using `rbenv` and `ruby-build` in tandem.

Something in the RDoc compilation process must take up a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this "solution" works:

Compile `ruby-2.0.0-p247` with the following flags:

```
./configure prefix=/change_this/to/your/needs --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
```

Those flags are the same ones used by RVM.  `puma`, `thin`, and `unicorn` all install fine.

*Note:* rbenv users: change `prefix=` to your .rbenv/versions directory.

Answer (score 0):

@patcoll and @dgo.a are both correct: The failure is due to a lack of available memory. Disabling RDoc installation will resolve this.

However, you do not need to manually `./configure` or enable shared rbenv.

Instead, install Ruby using rbenv's configure env var:

```
export CONFIGURE_OPTS="--disable-install-doc"; rbenv install 2.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rbenv and with 512MB of memory it still failed, so:

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--disable-install-doc" rbenv install 2.1.2
```

It turns out that memory is not the issue, its disk space. Review your logs folders (`du -sh`).

Answer (score 0):

When building Ruby 2 from source, configure with docs disabled if getting the `make: *** [rdoc] Error 137` error.

```
./configure --disable-install-doc
```

This issue seems to occur in low memory environments (less than 512MB).